# adding numbers using if/else statements?

Tags: python

```
def main():
    total = 0
    print('Welcome to the Dew Drop Inn!')
    print('Please enter your choices as y or n.')
    print('     ')
    cheese = (input('Do you want a grilled cheese? '))
    dog = (input('Do you want a hot dog? ')) 
    nacho = (input('Do you want nachos? '))
    burger = (input('Do you want a hamburger? '))
    grilled_cheese = 5
    hot_dog = 5
    nachos = 4
    hamburger = 6
    cheese_burger = 1
    if cheese == 'y':
        total + grilled_cheese
    if dog == 'y':
        total + hot_dog
    if nacho == 'y':
        total + nachos
    if burger == 'y':
        total + hamburger
        the_cheese_please = input('Do you want cheese on that? ')
        if the_cheese_please == 'y':
            total + cheese_burger
    else:
        total + 0

    print('     ')
    print('The total for your food is $',(total),'.')
    tip = total * 1.15


main()
```

I need to be able to add up the numbers from the the user tells me. Depending on what food they want, how do I go about adding up the numbers using if/else statements? The max number of if's is 5 and the max number of else's is 1. I am very new at this so I apologize if this comes across as naive, but it would really help me out if someone gave me a tip on this. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is wrong with the code that you posted?

Comment: You're one nice tipper, sure it shouldn't be `tip = total * 0.15`?

Comment: Running this code through a tool such as pylint or using a proper python ide would highlight the issue quite quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`total + grilled_cheese` and other similar lines do nothing useful. They add the 2 numbers together, but don't do anything with the result. It would be the same as having say, a `2` just floating around in your code.

You need to reassign the result back to `total`:

```
total = total + grilled_cheese
```

Or more succinctly

```
total += grilled_cheese
```

Answer (score 1):

In each of your if statements you have done:

```
total + grilled_cheese
```

etc. This isn't the way you increment your value of total in python.

Instead you want to do:

```
total += grilled_cheese
```

and your else statement isn't needed; if your if statement runs then the total will increase but if it doesn't run (the input is 'n') then the total won't change.

Your code will look almost the same:

```
def main():
total = 0
print('Welcome to the Dew Drop Inn!')
print('Please enter your choices as y or n.')
print('     ')
cheese = (input('Do you want a grilled cheese? '))
dog = (input('Do you want a hot dog? ')) 
nacho = (input('Do you want nachos? '))
burger = (input('Do you want a hamburger? '))
grilled_cheese = 5
hot_dog = 5
nachos = 4
hamburger = 6
cheese_burger = 1
if cheese == 'y':
    total += grilled_cheese
if dog == 'y':
    total += hot_dog
if nacho == 'y':
    total += nachos
if burger == 'y':
    total += hamburger
    the_cheese_please = input('Do you want cheese on that? ')
    if the_cheese_please == 'y':
        total += cheese_burger


print('     ')
print('The total for your food is $',(total),'.')
tip = total * 1.15


main()
```